# Parallel implementation loses efficiency with large numbers

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I implemented two versions of the classical dynamic programming algorithm for the knapsack problem: a sequential one and a parallel one. When the capacity is small (< 500 000), the parallel version is almost two times faster. However, with larger capacities (> 1 000 000), the parallel version becomes slower than the sequential one. Why? Is there a way to fix it?

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct Item { int64_t w, p; };
struct Instance { std::vector<Item> items; int64_t c; };

int64_t opt_bellman_array(const Instance& ins)
{
    int64_t n = ins.items.size();
    std::vector<int64_t> values(ins.c + 1, 0);
    for (int64_t j=0; j<n; ++j)
        for (int64_t x=ins.c; x>=ins.items[j].w; x--)
            if (values[x] < values[x - ins.items[j].w] + ins.items[j].p)
                values[x] = values[x - ins.items[j].w] + ins.items[j].p;
    return values[ins.c];
}

/******************************************************************************/

void opts_bellmanpar_array(const Instance& ins,
        int64_t n1, int64_t n2, std::vector<int64_t>::iterator values)
{
    for (int64_t j=n1; j<n2; ++j)
        for (int64_t x=ins.c; x>=ins.items[j].w; x--)
            if (*(values + x) < *(values + x - ins.items[j].w) + ins.items[j].p)
                *(values + x) = *(values + x - ins.items[j].w) + ins.items[j].p;
}

int64_t opt_bellmanpar_array(const Instance& ins)
{
    int64_t n = ins.items.size();
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return ins.items[0].p;
    }

    int64_t k = (n - 1) / 2 + 1;

    std::vector<int64_t> values1(ins.c + 1, 0);
    std::thread thread(opts_bellmanpar_array, std::ref(ins), 0, k, values1.begin());
    std::vector<int64_t> values2(ins.c + 1, 0);
    opts_bellmanpar_array(std::ref(ins), k, n, values2.begin());
    thread.join();

    int64_t opt = -1;
    for (int64_t c1=0; c1<=ins.c; ++c1) {
        int64_t z = values1[c1] + values2[ins.c - c1];
        if (opt < z)
            opt = z;
    }
    return opt;
}

/******************************************************************************/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    int64_t n = 500;
    int64_t r = 10000;
    Instance ins;
    ins.c = 200000;
    //ins.c = 2000000;

    ins.items = std::vector<Item>(n);
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int64_t> d(1, r);
    for (int64_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        ins.items[i].w = d(generator);
        ins.items[i].p = d(generator);
    }

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    opt_bellman_array(ins);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    opt_bellmanpar_array(ins);
    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> timespan1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    std::chrono::duration<double> timespan2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t3 - t2);

    std::cout << "seq " << timespan1.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "par " << timespan2.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation command:

```
g++ -O3 test.cpp -o test -lpthread
```

Ouput for ins.c = 200000

```
seq 0.071924
par 0.0388827
```

Ouput for ins.c = 2000000

```
seq 0.975181
par 1.08307
```

Comment: Pls add the output as well.

Comment: Maybe because you copy large amount of data from `ins` to `values1` and `values2` when execute concurently? I.e. `std::vector<int64_t> values1(ins.c + 1, 0);`

Comment: @vahancho for me, only the iterator is copied, not the whole vector, isn't it?

Comment: False sharing maybe?

Comment: Since you have a few operation that depend on the size of ins.c, it might help to break up the time measurements, and see which of those operations is taking too long.

Comment: @fflorian, well, in case of capacity 1000000 `std::vector<int64_t> values1(ins.c + 1, 0);` allocates memory for 1000001 elements. You do it twice. I think it will take some additional time. Your single threaded function doesn't do it and for small capacities it performs slower than multithreaded function. But for larger capacities the results may be different.

Comment: @vahancho (and artcorpse) both the allocation and the merge operation at the end seem to take negligible time compared to the inner for loops (less than 0.01s). It doesn't seem to me that the issue might be related to these operations